# Script for stopping the same docker container

Tags: bash, docker, shell, docker-compose

So I have an app deployed with docker but I'm tired to delete and rebuild the image everytime so i used wrote a script to do everything for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
docker-compose ps # lists all services (id, name)
docker-compose stop dee506ab283a #this will stop only the selected container
docker-compose rm dee506ab283a # this will remove the docker container permanently
docker-compose up
```

The problem is that the container wont have the same id everytime so this only works once. How can I get the new generated id so I can just run this script everytime?

Comment: @JBallin how can i tag the image in dockerfile? or in docker-compose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `container_name` to the service in your `docker-compose.yml` file like so:

```yaml
services:
...
  postgres:
    container_name: my-container
    image: postgres:12.1-alpine
...
```

Then you can use the following `docker` commands to do what you're looking for:

```bash
docker-compose ps
docker stop my-container
docker rm my-container
docker-compose up
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be enough to run

```bash
docker-compose up --build -d
```

without doing any of the other steps you describe.  This will rebuild any image you mention with a `build:` description in the Compose file, and then delete and recreate any containers whose configuration or images have changed.

If you do need any of the other commands, all of the imperative `docker-compose` commands accept the Compose service names as arguments; `docker-compose stop app` for example.  You do not need to look up the container ID or manually specify the container name.